# ManyToMany relation for objects with same column name for id's

Tags: java, spring

I have 2 classes: `User`, `Role`

`Role` is defined as:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Role")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="RoleId")
    private long id;
    ....
}
```

`User` is defined as:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="User")
public class User implements UserDetails { 

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="UserId")
    private long id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "User_Role", 
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Id"), 
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;
    .....
   }
```

Apparently having two columns with similar names for the id's causes the following error to be thrown:

```
Repeated column in mapping for collection: com.myproject.security.model.User.roles column: id
```

How should I fix this issue ? When I rename the columns to `RoleId` and `UserId` there's no error.

Comment: is this even possible? do you have a table named User_Role with two identical columNames?

Comment: it should probably besomething like :@JoinTable(name = "User_Role", 
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userId"), 
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "roleId"))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

joinColumns and inverseJoinColumns will be columns in table User_Role, you cannot have two columns with the same name in the same table

Comment: how does it select which columns of each object/table to use?

Comment: the joinColumns will be your owning entity which has the @JoinTable annotation, and the inverseJoinColumns will be the non owning entity

Comment: Is it always the attribute annotated with `@Id` ?

Comment: yes the value will be the id for each entity, but the name of joinColumns,inverseJoinColumns could be anything

Answer (score 1):

You have explicitly told Hibernate (or whatever JPA implementation you're using) that both user ID and role ID should be stored in the column named *Id* in the table named *User_Role*.

Since they reference different entities they need to be different columns, this is probably what you want to do:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "User_Role", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "UserId"), 
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "RoleId"))
private Set<Role> roles;
```

This way you will store the ID of the user in *UserId* and the ID of the role in *RoleId*.